# Failed certificate check with git for all https repositories but just 1 user

Tags: git, ssl, curl, ca

For a few days now, I can't `git clone` (or `git fetch`) any of my https repositories (hosted on different servers):

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://git.weboob.org/weboob/weboob.git
Cloning into 'weboob'...
* Couldn't find host git.weboob.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 136.243.171.154:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to git.weboob.org (136.243.171.154) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.weboob.org/weboob/weboob.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

This is only a problem for 1 user on this computer: creating a test user with a new home directory makes it work:

```
Cloning into 'weboob'...
* Couldn't find host git.weboob.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 136.243.171.154:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to git.weboob.org (136.243.171.154) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=git.weboob.org
*  start date: Jan 20 01:12:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 19 01:12:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "git.weboob.org" matched cert's "git.weboob.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /weboob/weboob.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: git.weboob.org
User-Agent: git/2.24.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache
...
```

As you can see, the difference is that these lines don't appear for my main user:

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I would like to fix the problem for my main user without getting rid of my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on `#git`'s IRC channel helped me found the problem. The broken user had a different `git` command in its `PATH` and in its `GIT_EXEC_PATH`. Removing this git and cleaning the environment variable fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A recent version of GitLab resulted in a similar error message:

```
$ git clone https://git.example.ch/test/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.example.ch/test/test.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

The reasons seems to be that it aborted the connection instead of asking for HTTP credentials on private repositories. A GitLab update fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

increase buffer size

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Then I checked the users in the server and my user name was removed. So I recreated the file using following command *sudo htpasswd -c /etc/users uditrawat03*

I hope this will work for you